# OCaml multiline string with ocamlformat produces ugly results

Tags: ocaml, ocamlformat

I have this sql query to build a table in Sqlite3, I'm using a multiline string which works fine.

```
let create_blog_table db =
  let sql =
    "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        author TEXT NOT NULL,
        content TEXT NOT NULL);
    "
  in
  match exec db sql with Rc.OK -> () | _ -> failwith "Error creating table"
```

But when I run `dune fmt` (with ocamlformat installed) it results in this:

```
let create_blog_table db =
  let sql =
    "\n\
    \        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog(\n\
    \        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n\
    \        author TEXT NOT NULL,\n\
    \        content TEXT NOT NULL);\n\
    \    "
  in
  match exec db sql with Rc.OK -> () | _ -> failwith "Error creating table"
```

Is this formatting necessary or desirable for some reason?

If not, can I tell it not to do that?

I found the rule `break-string-literals` but that only allows `auto` or `never`

.ocamlformat

```
profile = default 
version = 0.26.0

break-string-literals=auto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly for this purpose, OCaml offers [quoted string literal](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/lex.html#sss:stringliterals) that a delimited with `{|` and `|}`, e.g.,

```
  let sql =
    {|
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        author TEXT NOT NULL,
        content TEXT NOT NULL);
    |}
  in
```

And ocamlformat won't touch anything inside the quoted string literal, letting you format it the way you like.

It's also worth noting that building SQL statements is much easier with the string extrapolation offered by [ppx_string](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_string). For example, suppose you don't want to hardcode the names of the tables and columns in each statement and bind them to variables,

```
let table_name = "blog"
let id = "id"
let author = "author"
let content = "content"

let sql =
  [%string
    {|
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %{table_name} (
          %{id} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          %{author} TEXT NOT NULL,
          %{content} TEXT NOT NULL
        );
    |}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `never` for `--break-string-literals` retains your formatting.

```
$ cat > test.ml
let x = "
  hello
  world
"

let () = print_endline x
$ ocamlformat --enable-outside-detected-project test.ml
let x = "\n  hello\n  world\n"
let () = print_endline x
$ cat > test.ml
let x = "
  hello
  world
"

let () = print_endline x
$ ocamlformat --enable-outside-detected-project --break-string-literals=never test.ml
let x = "
  hello
  world
"

let () = print_endline x
$
```

As regards your example, with `--break-string-literals` set to `auto`, indentation can be maintained. It only seems unnecessary because your code has started out well-indented. It helps that the exact formatting of your string isn't crucial in this case.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for clarifying that. I will have to try it again, when I set never the first time around it just inlined the string.